# Ubuntu Server ISO for VMware Player

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

Where can I find an Ubuntu Server ISO to use (convert to a VM) in VMware Player?

Answer (score 2):

From Ubuntu's website, of course. :-) You don't need a special VMWare only ISO.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server

Comment: I recently installed the 12.04 server (using Virtualbox, though) to check it out, and found [Ubuntu's server documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html) which is a great step-by-step guide to installing things like LAMP apps, wiki (wikimedia, as used by Wikipedia), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Ubuntu server virtual images from VMware's repository for images here:

- [VMware virtual appliance marketplace](https://solutionexchange.vmware.com/store/category_groups/virtual-appliances)

You can search for the image you want in the search box to the left. However, if you are looking for the generic ISO for ubuntu server, follow [reverendj1](https://askubuntu.com/users/53455/reverendj1)'s answer.